# Angular 7 SELECT option not selected on initialize

Tags: angular

I have a `select` with string `option`'s. When I get the model back from backend, the selected value does not populate on page load. I compared the model string with the selected item in the `select` and it returns `true`, meaning it has the same value.
Here's my code:

```html
<select name="province" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="branch.PhysicalProvince">
   <option *ngFor="let p of branchService.provinces" [value]="p">{{p}}</option>
</select>
```

So `branch.PhysicalProvince` is 'Western Cape' and that value does exist in the `branchService.provinces` array.

If I do `branch.PhysicalProvince == branchService.provinces[1]` in the HTML, it shows `true`.

I also tried `[(ngValue)]="p"` on the `option`.

Any idea why the value does not populate?

Comment: Any error on console?

Comment: @AmitChigadani no errors in the console. The dropdown list works fine, if I select an item and save, it saves it to the database.

Comment: in place `[(ngModel)]` try `[(value)]`

Comment: I dont see any issue in your code. Check this code sample https://stackblitz.com/edit/dropdown-select-angular-init?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @ashishpal I tried it now, also not working, but thanks.

Comment: @AmitChigadani that's why I don't understand it, that is the correct way to populate select dropdowns, but it's not working. Another dropdown is working perfectly fine, just this 1

Comment: check if the name is equals to other select element, if dont, use compareWith function

Comment: @Gaspar thanks man. I saw there was a dropdown with same `name` attribute. You can post this as the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check if your entire html component have unique name attribute, somehow Angular lost model values if there is the same name attribute in other elements.

Answer (score 2):

Use compareWith function:

```html
<select name="province" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="branch.PhysicalProvince"
   [compareWith]="compareFn">
   <option *ngFor="let p of branchService.provinces" [value]="p">{{p}}</option>
</select>
```

```js
compareFn(compared1: { id: number }, compared2: { id: number }) {
    return compared1 && compared2 ? compared1.id === compared2.id : compared1 === compared2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [selected] attribute on  tag then it will work.